# Centrifugal force on a pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

Why don't we consider the centrifugal force acting on the bob of a pendulum while drawing the Free Body Diagram of a pendulum? It's also a sort of circular motion.

Comment: The only forces acting on the bob are gravity and the tension in the string. How can any other force be acting?

Comment: Centrifugal force. We've to consider that if we are in an inertial frame, right?

Comment: The description of the pendulum is in an inertial frame, unless you want to torture yourself with a description as seen from a person who is riding on the pendulum. I think they call that the "Miley Cyrus f(r)ame" these days. ;-)

Comment: Strictly speaking the asker is correct: there is centripetal force needed to keep the bob on it's circular arc trajectory. But for the small angle approximation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)#Small-angle_approximation) we don't need to take it into account. To paraphrase CuriousOne: we're not masochists!

Comment: @CuriousOne, that was a good one.  I might get a chance to use that comment in the class room.

Comment: @DavidWhite: I am assuming you are teaching college and not high school physics? We don't want you to lose your job over a harmless joke between adults. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne, I'm teaching AP Physics C, which is college level physics, to high school seniors.  Thanks for your concern.  If I allude to Miley Cirus, I'll keep my comments G rated.

Comment: @DavidWhite: Be careful, though, your students probably know way more about her and how the video was shot than you do. Riding a ball is not easy (I can see a stability problem coming!), so one wonders if they had to glue her on? Maybe that thing is worth an entire lesson? "Wrecking ball riding for absolute beginners and Level C physics students". :-)

Comment: @Gery John already identified the centripetal force for this case. It is the tension less $mg \cos \theta$. Centripetal force is not a kind of force in its own right. It is a label applied to a combination of real forces.

Comment: SO, that centripetal force thingie is included within the tensional force supplied by the string?

Answer (score 4):

> Why don't we consider the centrifugal force acting on the bob of a pendulum while drawing the Free Body Diagram of a pendulum? It's also a sort of circular motion.

First off, you meant centripetal rather than centrifugal. Circular motion requires a centripetal force, not a centrifugal force.

---

There are two forces acting on the pendulum bob: Gravitation, which is a constant force, and tension (or sometimes compression in the case of an inverted pendum) which is always directed toward or away from the central pivot about which the pendulum bob rotates. This tensile or compressive force is a constraint force. The magnitude and direction are always just that amount needed to keep the net radial component of force to be $m v^2/r$, directed toward the central pivot.

That tensile/compressive force does not need to be modeled -- unless one is asked "Will the pendulum rod (or string) break or buckle?" Assuming the rod/string does not break or buckle, the only motion of interest results from the tangential component of the net force. You don't need to model the radial component of the net force so long as the tensile/compressive force along/against the pendulum rod can satisfy the constraint.

Comment: All together now: "Constraint forces do no work!"